# ODBC crashed while inserting supplementary characters via MySql

Tags: c++, mysql, utf-8, odbc, supplementary

I am connecting to MySql version 5.5 through ODBC Mysql Connector version 5.3.

To insert supplementary characters, I changed the corresponding Character set and Collation to utf8mb4.

Through Odbc, I am able to insert characters within utf8 range but as soon as I tried inserting supplementary characters then it got crashed.

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hmmm; someone else asked a very similar question.  Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715346/sqlexecdirectw-crash-while-inserting-unicode-supplementary-characters-through-od